# JavaScript array access issues

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a loop as follows. That needs to update a score by counting, how many tiles a player has. As per comments, the toy can see, which accessors work and which don't:

```
Player.prototype.calculateScore = function(){
    for(i = 0; i < 9; i ++){

        //works and prints tile1 player contents
        console.log(game.tile.tile1.player);

        //doesnt work 
        console.log(game.tile['tile' + i]['player']);

        //works and prints the entire tile1 object
        console.log(game.tile['tile' + i]);

        //if(game.tile['tile' + i]['player'] == this.name){
        //  this.score = this.score + 1;
        //}
    }
}
```

here is the object containing the data

```
function Game(){
    this.tile = {
        'tile1' : {card: '', player: ''},
        'tile2' : {card: '', player: ''},
        'tile3' : {card: '', player: ''},
        'tile4' : {card: '', player: ''},
        'tile5' : {card: '', player: ''},
        'tile6' : {card: '', player: ''},
        'tile7' : {card: '', player: ''},
        'tile8' : {card: '', player: ''},
        'tile9' : {card: '', player: ''}
    };
```

Am I trying to access it incorrectly? I am currently running code on a node.js server running with socket.io .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `'tile1'` ..... `'tile9'` but  your first loop iteration will look for `tile0` cause `var i = 0`

**`tile0` does not exists**. Create it, or use:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(game.tile['tile' + i].player); // will work cause "tile1" exits
}
```

Furthermore, the reason that `console.log(game.tile['tile' + i]);` works, is cause in the next loop iteration where `var i=1` >> `'tile1'` gets called and returned, and no `null` properties like `["tile0"]["player"]` were tried to get accessed.

Comment: thank you soo much so simple and it makes sense just been up all nite trying to gets things finished off and polished for hand in :D

Comment: @andrewhutchings nothing to worry about. Take some good sleep and happy coding.